# How to use Kitsune Schema's to add category, sub category and then product structure to showcase products?

Tags: arrays, schema

We have created a testing project to test schema of Category > Sub-Category > Product. We are not able to get the multiple Sub_Categories out of k-repeat tag. (Array of Categories > Array of Sub_Categories > Array of Products)

**Main Schema**

category[]: categories

**Data Types:**

category

```
            string:name

            sub_category[]: sub_categories

            product[]: cat_products
```

sub_category

```
            string:name

            product[]: sc_products
```

product

```
            string:name

            string:content

            image[]:image
```

**Code**

```
<div k-repeat="[[business.categories, i, 0:business.categories.length()]]" >
        <!--Category: [[business.categories[i].name]]<br>-->
        Sub Category: [[business.categories[i].sub_categories[i].name]], <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What kind of programming language is that?

Comment: Kitsune is the full stack platform, where you can optimise and create your own dynamic website using its own language. You can visit getkitsune.com

Answer (score 3):

Solution to your problem is nested loop.

In your case :

let your base class be "test"

```html
<div k-repeat="[[test.categories, i, 0:test.categories.length()]]">
  This is category name = [[test.categories[i].name]]
  <div k-repeat="[[test.categories[i].sub_categories, j, 0:test.categories[i].sub_categories.length()]]">
    Sub category name = [[test.categories[i].sub_categories[j].name]]
  </div>
</div>
```